# 'We were connected at the most primal level'

Tags: meaning

What does 'We were connected at the most primal level' mean?

context as follows:

> Edie: "Oh right. You know, I can only imagine how worried you must be."
>
> Felicia: "I'm not worried, Edie. Martha and I had a very intense bond. **We were connected at the most primal level**, and a few days ago, I felt this sensation in my soul.

Comment: have you looked up the words ***connected, primal***, and ***level***?

Comment: yes,I do.connected means there is some kind of relationship between people.

Comment: I have no idea the full sentence's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

[This use of *primal* is this sense from](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/primal) Oxford Dictionaries

> *Psychology* Relating to or denoting the needs, fears, or behaviour that are postulated (especially in Freudian theory) to form the origins of emotional life.
>   *‘he preys on people's primal fears’*

Felicia is saying that they have a connection that's based on very primative emotions, rather than rationality.

Comment: thanks,Barmar.I get it! I have a hunch that it is very difficult to get the TV line,what do you think of it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But the statement is often an exaggeration.